# Webpage not available on Honeycomb webview

Tags: android, webview, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-assets

We have a webview that we are loading from android_assets.  This works fine in 2.1, 2.2, and 2.3.  However, when we load it in 3.0, we get a "Webpage not available" message.

This only happens on pages where we are passing parameters to the webview:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "androidInterface");

webView.setBackgroundColor(0);
//This works
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/my.html");
//This does not work.
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/my.html" + "?param=value");
```

Any idea how to get this to work on Honeycomb?

Comment: silly question, does it work when u concat the string in a local var?

Comment: No, that didn't help.  I also saw another question, where urlencoding helped with spaces, but that didn't help in this situation either.

Comment: I got the same problem.. My code works on android 2.3.3 but dousnt on android 4.0.. (saying webpage unavailable when passing a param) Did u found a solution?

Comment: No, but see my post below in the answers for the workaround that I used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not answer to the original problem, but a workaround.  Since I was already using the JavascriptInterface, I set the value that I wanted to read in Javascript on the JavascriptInterface.